# Increasing the size of training set prevents training of convolutional neural network

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN for binary image classification. With a training set of about ~1024 entries the net overtrains but validation accuracy increases to about 80%.

When I increase the training set size to around 2048 or 4096 (and change nothing else) the network does not learn at all. Neither training nor validation accuracy increases over 50%.

I have no hypotheses for how this could happen. Does anyone have any theories to explain how simply increasing training set size could hinder CNN training?

Comment: Are you using minibatches (cf stochastic gradient descent)? Or are you training the network on the entire data set all at once in each round of weight updates?